# how to prevent input text edit values in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have built simple project using asp.net core.
I have disabled input text to prevent end user to edit its value but while inspect and specify this input I can edit its value easy and I can to save new value into database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n0Fu.png)

the Question is:
how can I prevent this action to happen?

Comment: Use serverside validation.. As anyone can also send data without any browser(using any http client)

Answer (score 0):

Well, client-side is where the use has full access to it and can alter any Javascript, Html,  Css,...  Code and it has no security, you can consider disabling button just as note for user that it is not going to be updated, but what ever reason that made you set it as disabled, you should check the same condition again in server- side and decide whether to save it or not.

All real validations should be on server-side. For example the code we create in javascript ro prevent posting forms if there is any empty required fields is just to prevent sending too many requests to server (that we know it will fail) but we know that the use can post anything anyways if they really want to, changing some javascript code or using apps like postman. Remember final check should always happen on server.